# Is it possible to route two connectors on a same high speed bus?

Tags: pcb-design, high-speed

I was making a PCB design in which I need to connect a high speed (1Gbps) DSI bus to a FFC connector.

The problem is I need to test 2 displays which have different types of connectors so I was thinking of routing the DSI bus to the first connector which will then go on to the second connector.

If only one of the connectors are in use at any time, do the extra wires at the end cause any issues? Like acting as an antenna?

[image]

Comment: It may. Can you add more details, like the signalling standard, termination on the far end and expected to be attached to either connector, and the distance between the two connectors?

Comment: A few additional tricks, which may minimize stubs. Placing the footprint in footprint, so that only one connector can be mounted at a time, and placing jumper resistors, if appropriate, to disconnect the longer stub for production.

Comment: It's not so much that it could act as an antenna... the problem with daisy chaining like this is it disrupts the characteristic impedance of your PCB traces.  It can cause signal reflections which can corrupt the normal data transfer (because the 1's and 0's don't look like clean 1's and 0's anymore).   Suggest you find an expert or at least get educated on high-speed design (Howard Johnsons book is a great introduction - http://www.sigcon.com/books/bookHSDD.html)

Comment: Mount the connectors on opposite sides of a small carrier PCB so they are both pretty much at the end of the cable.

Comment: Can you just add jumpers to route it to one connector or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not all that familiar with the DSI specification, but...

It's a differential high speed interface, right?  Like all high-speed interfaces, the bus needs to be properly terminated.  In the case of DSI, I assume this termination needs to go at the destination (far end of the bus).  Also, there needs to be a constant, +/-10% characteristic impedance Zo carried through the entire interface.  All wires/cables should be twisted shielded pairs (TSPs), IMO.

Finally, like Justme said, stubs should be avoided at these speeds.

If these guidelines are followed, you should be able to make this work with either connector configuration.  But, like all high speed designs, the devil is in the details.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not a good idea. It's not just about the board: any cable you attach will make a large stub and will disrupt the signal integrity.

Consider using some kind of LVDS fan-out buffer instead to replicate the signal to each display.

You also need to contend with each display's I2C interface separately, as the two displays could clash if they're connected together.

Answer (score 1):

Stubs are always bad for high speed signals.

Whether or not if affects your design or not depends on many factors such as length of the stub and rise time of the signal.

Comment: thank you for your answer.